# Render Counter Collections Sort Order

Tags: python, django, collections

I can't figure out how to display a collections.Counter in the right order in Django: When i use Counter().most_common(5) it should give me the 5 most common keys in order. But it does not.

I've got this:

```
users_cities = dict(Counter(User.objects.all().values_list('city', flat=True)).most_common(5)) 
return render(request,'admin/stats/stats.html', { 'users_cities': users_cities, }
```

But when i loop through them in the template, they arent sorted:

```
{% for label , counter in users_cities.items %}
  {% if label %}
  <tr>
    <th>{{ label }}</th><td> {{ counter }}</td>
  </tr>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

So where is my mistake?

Comment: Converting to dict. There is the problem I think. Even dict(Counter(User.objects.all().values_list('city', flat=True)).most_common(5)) wont give you a dict which is ordered. Can you try in shell

Comment: Exactly as Daniel mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is nice that you got the answer. But I wont prefer to go for Counter as we have annotate in Django.

When you use Counter the code will be

```
users_cities = Counter(User.objects.all().values_list('city', flat=True)).most_common(5)
```

which results in an SQL query of

```
SELECT city FROM user
```

You can use annotate instead.

```
users_cities = User.objects.all().values('city').annotate(count = Count('city')).order_by('-count')[:5]
```

This results in a query of

```
SELECT city, COUNT(user.city) AS count FROM user GROUP BY user.city
```

ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 5

And the query time will also be less.

I hope that this helps. :)

Comment: Way more efficient solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You extracted the most common, but then put them back into a new dict. Dicts are unordered.

Skip the `dict` call and just iterate through the result you get from `most_common`.

Comment: Why not? `most_common()` gives you a list of tuples, just iterate through that in exactly the same way.

Comment: Yes you are right! I got rid of dict() and therefore had to get rid of .items as well and its working! Wohooo Thanks!